# List of possible error codes from Google Play Android Developer REST API

Tags: android, google-api, google-play

I'm currently using the Google Play Android Developer REST API to validate user subscriptions server side.

There are a couple of different error messages that I seem to get back. Some that indicate that the subscription does not exist or is not valid and some others that say "backendError".

**Question:** I'm looking for a list of possible error code, so I can determine if I should try it again or if it's not valid.

Comment: Some of those exceptions are documented on the various package API pages [that can be found here](http://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html).  (The exception lists can be found near the bottom of many package API pages.)

Comment: this looks like the android SDK. I'm looking for something for the Google Play REST API

Comment: Well, glad we got that cleared up...

Comment: And if you haven't already, you might also want to try checking the [Google Product Forums](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fproductforums.google.com%2Fd%2Fforum%2Fen&ei=pYdLUbIVh6GIAtu-gNgI&usg=AFQjCNHTRt0abLwdnL8DQbHaxMoyjRVwvg&bvm=bv.44158598,d.cGE) for something like this.

Comment: anyone found possible error codes?